# when creating a project in angular 16.1.3 and using ng serve it shows error like this and can't compile it

Tags: angular, angular-material

./node_modules/@angular/common/fesm2022/common.mjs - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/tools/babel/webpack-loader.js):
TypeError: C:\Users\kamil\Desktop\practice\app\node_modules@angular\common\fesm2022\common.mjs: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'file')

./node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm2022/platform-browser.mjs - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/tools/babel/webpack-loader.js):
TypeError: C:\Users\kamil\Desktop\practice\app\node_modules@angular\platform-browser\fesm2022\platform-browser.mjs: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'file')

./node_modules/@angular/router/fesm2022/router.mjs - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/tools/babel/webpack-loader.js):
TypeError: C:\Users\kamil\Desktop\practice\app\node_modules@angular\router\fesm2022\router.mjs: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'file')

** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **

× Failed to compile.

i wanted to create a project but i can't do it now.